# Can an Android textView become frozen if two threads try to access the same referenced object at the same time?

Tags: android, textfield

Can a thread trying to access the same part of memory at the same time as another thread cause textViews on an android to freeze? if so what is the solution?

Comment: Do you have an example or specific problem?

Comment: You realize how simple this is to test, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the design of Android. The method calls to change something in the appearance of a TextView must be called within the Android-UI Thread. You get an exception, if you call methods like `TextView.setText()` from another thread.

The proposed solution for this is to call `Activity.runOnUiThread()` or similar and pass your changes to the runnable. See the [Android guide about multithreading](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) for more information and the different possiblities.

Answer (score 1):

I never read about View' Thread safety concept in android Documentation. But i guess you will get exception because Changing by two Thread at a time is not good user experience. My conclusion is View are Thread safe and always be updated in UI thread.